# How can I use 2 MediaElements at the same time?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I'm creating a mini game. It has music background and gun sound. But I can not play them at the same time.
How can I do it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Detaileddescription):

> When a MediaElement control plays audio or video content, any background sounds or media already playing are halted. The app launches the playback experience when the user taps the control. Only one MediaElement control can operate at a time.

Instead you can try to use [SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx) from XNA to play your gun sound.

Comment: But I didn't use XNA, I use silverlight to create a game.

Comment: @Carson You don't use XNA because you don't want to or you aren't able to do so?